# Symbols in androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, encoding, apk

When I open an `androidmanifest.xml` file it appears as all nonsense symbols that I can't read. How do I convert these symbols to human-readable letters and code?

Comment: which editor or IDE are you using?

Comment: Can you post a sample or screenshot of it?

Comment: the file should be readable with a text editor - what are you opening it with?

Comment: BatteryAcid : it isn't readable with text editor .... it look like symbols

Comment: Armando SM : i will try that now

Comment: Aakash : I'm tried to open it with lot of them 
I tried to open it with notepad++ /android studio / Eclipse/ TortoiseSVN / Visual SVN but it still look like symbols

Comment: Which manifest are you trying to open? I mean, where did you get it?

Comment: where does this manifest come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we can resolve this problem by using either android commands or android app that special used for read files that called androidmainfest.xml